# CTE arithmetic shift operator causes arithmetic overflow error

Tags: sql, sql-server

When executing a CTE expression to query for an ordered child parent relation by using a shift, it fails with

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type bigint

The problem is that the shift value becomes big very easily. I know I could increase the datatype to support 38 numeric values but I would still hit this number when having deep parent child relations. I'm wondering if there are any other method to order the results, so I would not hit this limit.

Here is a sample script that shows the increase of the shift parameter.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ParentChild] (
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ParentId] [int] NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Dialog] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ParentChild]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ParentChild_ParentId] FOREIGN KEY([ParentId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[ParentChild] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ParentChild] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ParentChild_ParentId]
GO

set identity_insert [dbo].[ParentChild] on
insert into [dbo].[ParentChild] ([Id], [ParentId],[Name])
values 
(1, NULL, '1'),
(2, NULL, '2'),
(3, 1, '1.1'),
(4, 1, '1.2'),
(5, 2, '2.1'),
(6, 5, '2.1.1')
set identity_insert [dbo].[ParentChild] off

-- without shift
with Parent as (
        select d1.[Id], d1.[ParentId], d1.[Name], 0 AS [Level]
        FROM [dbo].[ParentChild] as d1
        WHERE d1.[ParentId] IS NULL
    UNION ALL
        SELECT d2.Id, d2.ParentId, d2.[Name], [Level] + 1
        FROM [dbo].[ParentChild] as d2
        INNER JOIN Parent d1 ON d1.[Id] = d2.ParentId
    )

    select p.Id, p.ParentId, p.[Name], [Level]
    from Parent p
    group by p.Id, p.ParentId, p.[Name], [Level];

-- desired  
with Parent as (
    select d1.[Id], d1.[ParentId], d1.[Name], 0 AS [Level],
    CAST(row_number() over(order by id) as DECIMAL(38,0)) as [shift]
    FROM [dbo].[ParentChild] as d1
    WHERE d1.[ParentId] IS NULL
UNION ALL
    SELECT d2.Id, d2.ParentId, d2.[Name], [Level] + 1, 
    CAST([shift] * 100 + row_number() over(order by d2.id) as DECIMAL(38,0))
    FROM [dbo].[ParentChild] as d2
    INNER JOIN Parent d1 ON d1.[Id] = d2.ParentId
)

select p.Id, p.ParentId, p.[Name], [Level], [shift]
from Parent p
group by p.Id, p.ParentId, p.[Name], [Level], [shift]
order by cast([shift] as varchar(50))
```

Output without the shift parameter

```
Id  ParentId    Name    Level
1   NULL        1       0
2   NULL        2       0
3   1           1.1     1
4   1           1.2     1
5   2           2.1     1
6   5           2.1.1   2
```

Output with the shift parameter (desired)

```
Id  ParentId    Name    Level   shift
1   NULL        1       0       1
3   1           1.1     1       101
4   1           1.2     1       102
2   NULL        2       0       2
5   2           2.1     1       201
6   5           2.1.1   2       20101
```

Comment: You need to think of a diff approach to calculate the shift, as every level is getting multiplied by 100, so in few level only you will be out of the data limit.

Comment: indeed, I understand that but I really cannot come up with any other approach :-(

Comment: Assuming you're not planning to do *maths* on the result (which seems unlikely given that you're overflowing any reasonable type supporting maths here), why are you not building this "shift" up as a string rather than a number?

Comment: This operation seems to be building something equivalent to `hierarhcyid`. Why not use the built-in type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we can make `shift` a string rather than a maths-supporting data type, we can just do this:

```
with Parent as (
    select d1.[Id], d1.[ParentId], d1.[Name], 0 AS [Level],
    CONVERT(varchar(max),row_number() over(order by id)) as [shift]
    FROM [dbo].[ParentChild] as d1
    WHERE d1.[ParentId] IS NULL
UNION ALL
    SELECT d2.Id, d2.ParentId, d2.[Name], [Level] + 1,
    shift + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2),row_number() over(order by d2.id)),2)
    FROM [dbo].[ParentChild] as d2
    INNER JOIN Parent d1 ON d1.[Id] = d2.ParentId
)
select p.Id, p.ParentId, p.[Name], [Level], [shift]
from Parent p
group by p.Id, p.ParentId, p.[Name], [Level], [shift]
order by shift
```

It produces different results if the row numbers can ever exceed 100 but that seems to lead to problems with this representation anyway (ambiguous encodings).

Comment: Perfect thanks! Can you explain your comment about ambiguous encodings a bit more in detail because I'm not completely following.

Comment: @emp - if one parent has more than 100 children, then my offered encoding creates identical `shift` values under the same parent. Your encoding makes them appear to belong to a different parent. Two unrelated rows will produce identical values in the `shift` column, either way.